# Usage of bunch adjectives, not just two or three

Tags: grammar, adjectives

- A barely visible shining thin blue transparent layer appears around the bulb.

Here I used 5 adjectives "barely visible", "shining", "thin", "blue", "transparent". Is this correct? Can I add so many adjectives in front of a noun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tossing the reader an arbitrary number of adjectives in a comma-separated list is not strictly forbidden, but it is hard to read and sounds unsophisticated.

Are all the descriptors strictly necessary? Does "barely visible" not adequately cover "thin" and "transparent"? Saying **A barely visible, shining blue layer appears around the bulb.** is more more readable.

You could try turning some of the adjectives into verbs or adverbs: **A thin, transparent layer appears around the bulb, shining with a barely visible blue light.**

Or work the descriptors into separate sentences. **A thin, blue, transparent layer appears around the bulb. Its light is barely visible in the room.**

Answer (score 0):

`Around the bulb appeared a thin blue layer, barely visible, yet shining` sounds marginally better, though it changes the structure of the sentence.

Comment: @snailplane - thank you. Does the sentence itself sounds ok?

Comment: both barely visible _and_ transparent contradict shining a bit. Although I have restructured it again. Maybe that sounds a bit better.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, several adjectives are possible (and allowed) before a noun. For instance,

> She wore some *shining costly heavy black Spanish leather riding* boots.

However, try to follow the [adjective orders](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adjectives/order-adjectives) whenever you use more than one objective for a noun.

> A barely visible shining thin blue transparent layer appears around the bulb - sounds okay to me.

Comment: You would do well to follow the advice of that page: **"It is very unusual to have more than three adjectives."**